# How to automate downloading Flash videos

Tags: flash, video, wget

Here is a web-page which contains a Flash video: http://nptel.iitm.ac.in/courses/106101007/1. On parsing the HTML, it is very easy to find that there is a `span` with id **player** whose `href` attribute contains the link to the video source. Once we have that link, it is trivial to automate the download process through say `wget`.

However, in most of the Flash based video sharing sites like Youtube, Metacafe, Dailymotion, such links are not there. Instead there are a series of `meta` tags within which I guess the link is hidden somewhere. How do I download such videos? What is the process softwares like Youtube downloaders follow to download such flash based video where the link to the actual resource is not mentioned anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General video downloading can get complicated, as you're noticing. The issue is that web pages can embed this general purpose programming language called JavaScript. This creates the possibility for an infinite number of ways to obscure the true video download URL.

You have observed that video download tools exist. Such tools need to be updated from time to time because they are engaged in an arms race with the maintainers of the video sites who generally wish to prevent people from downloading and saving content.

Sometimes, the video isn't even available via straight HTTP. Instead, it may require another protocol to stream (e.g., RTMP, RTSP, MMS). In those cases, another tool needs to be invoked.

In order to develop such a tool, it often takes a bit of JavaScript reverse engineering as well as a protocol analyzer or web browser network analysis tool. A decade ago, I wrote a tool to download WMV videos from a now-defunct music video website. I did it by using a network protocol analyzer to watch the various URLs that the browser would send to the site. Then I wrote a tool that mimicked the same conversation. Modern tools operate similarly. When my tool derived the true streaming URL, it passed the URL to a separate tool that was able to download and save MMS streams. Any time that the site would update its little conversation protocol (typically every few months), my script would break and I would have to expend the effort to upgrade it if I cared enough.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed as much. An ideal downloader should be HTML agnostic, but the video-mainternance guys ensure it is not so.. :) But I have Youtube downloaders which I don't update. How come it continues to download videos even after I see Youtube has changed their HTML substantially?

Comment: If they update the HTML without altering the underlying protocol that the downloader tool needs, the tool will continue to work. Generally, each video on YouTube has a unique key (e.g., "Gangnam Style" is '9bZkp7q19f0') and that maps to a video in some database (conceptually). There's a process to figure out the direct video URL based on that key and that process may or may not rely on HTML scraping and parsing.

Comment: Yeah, but the process is too complicated! I installed a network analyzer and observed what happens when a Youtube video is streaming..Found that lots of GET requests occur in succession (the URLs are pretty complex, couldn't find any logic/pattern), each request returning some binary data as response. I took one response and tried to play it in VLC, it wouldn't play.. :(

Comment: Check out a script called youtube-dl. It's written in Python and should run easily on Linux or Mac OS X, and will run on Windows if you install Python. It already knows the "secret handshake" so you could observe its operation using a network analyzer and probably arrive at the protocol much more quickly.